# OpenXml: Is there any way to calculate the height of a paragraph or table before append to body?

Tags: c#, ms-word, height, openxml, break

I need to add a page break in some cases, to keep a paragraph and a table on same page.

The problem is that the table is aligned to right and the paragraph is justified (appears around the table).

```
--- --- --- |   |
--- --- --- |   |
--- --- --- |   |
--- --- --- -----
--- --- --- -----
```

If the text is less than the table, only the paragraph goes to next page. Both have "Keep with next".

Comment: Is the font used always the same?

Comment: Yes, I use the same font.

Answer (score 0):

No, Open XML SDK is only a document format parser library. What you would like to achieve is "pagination" (a process that places all the content to pages) which is done by a document viewer application (such as MS Word) and there is no way to do it with Open XML SDK. For this task you will need a 3rd party solution that exposes pagination info.